# Change HTML using Xpath and DomDocument?

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

i have Following HTML src :

```
$content = "<table>

<tr>
  <td>AAA</td>
  <td>30,40 €</td>
  <td>41,10 €</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>BBB</td>
  <td>30,40 €</td>
  <td>41,10 €</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>CCC</td>
  <td>30,40 €</td>
  <td>41,10 €</td>
</tr>
</table>";
```

I want to update all 1st `<td>` in `<tr>`, to add a class on `<td>` :

```
<table>

    <tr>
      <td class='first'>AAA</td>
      <td>30,40 €</td>
      <td>41,10 €</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='first'>BBB</td>
      <td>30,40 €</td>
      <td>41,10 €</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='first'>CCC</td>
      <td>30,40 €</td>
      <td>41,10 €</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

I'm able to get the elements i want with this :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($table);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($content);

foreach($xpath->query('//td[1]') as $td){
    echo $td->nodeValue."\n\n";

}
```

However, i dont know how change the content to add my class.

You have ideas ?

Comment: Did you try `foreach($xpath->query('//td[1]') as $td){$td->setAttribute('class','first');}; echo $dom->saveHTML();`  ?

Comment: It works ! many thnaks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use [`setAttribute`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php) to add a class to your first `td` elements:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query('//td[1]') as $td) {
    $td->setAttribute('class', 'first');
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Note that you need to convert your utf-8 as DOMDocument doesn't understand it well. Also DOMXPath should refer to the DOMDocument, not the original HTML.

Output

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="first">AAA</td>
  <td>30,40 &euro;</td>
  <td>41,10 &euro;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="first">BBB</td>
  <td>30,40 &euro;</td>
  <td>41,10 &euro;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="first">CCC</td>
  <td>30,40 &euro;</td>
  <td>41,10 &euro;</td>
 </tr> 
</table>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/4ctgD)